# How to mock '@nestjs-modules/mailer' sendMail function in Unit testcase

Tags: node.js, express, mocking, nestjs, nodemailer

I have written code for sending Email using '@nestjs-modules/mailer, I want to mock the @nestjs-modules/mailer sendMail method,so that I will not interact with external APIs in Unittests.Below is the code which I written in my service.ts file. I am new to nestjs technology  and it will be great help if someone help me in this.

Can someone help me with unit testcase for below scenario.

```
    import { MailerService } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
    import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

    @Injectable()
    export class sendEmailService{
      constructor(private readonly sendMailService: MailerService) {}
      async SendEmail(result): Promise<string> {
          await this.sendMailService.sendMail({
            to: 'user2@abc.com',
            from: 'sender@abc.com',
            subject:'Testing mail'
          });
        return 'Success'
      }
    }
```

Comment: I see nothing to test but the calling of `sendEmail` method from `sendMailService` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) mock for the mailer service should be all you need.

```js
{
  provide: MailerService,
  useValue: {
    sendMail: jest.fn()
  }
}
```

Add that to your test's providers and you have it mocked.